# Categoría gramatical de "que" o "para" en algunas frases

Tags: uso-de-palabras, categorías-gramaticales

Considera las siguientes oraciones:

> I have something to say.
>
> I have work to do.

En español:

> Tengo algo que decir.
>
> Tengo tarea que hacer.

Entiendo que también se podrían escribir con "para" en lugar de "que".

¿Es cierto que se pueden intercambiar así?

¿Y qué es la categoría gramatical de estas palabras en esta situación?

Comment: Using "para" instead of "que" in those sentences sounds a bit "forced" in spanish from Spain. In my opinion, the use of "para" involves a nuance of which is the important matter in the action. "Tengo algo para decir" would hint "the important thing here is to say something, and I have found something", while "Tengo algo que decir" would hint "the important thing here is me, who has something to say". However, the hint is quite subtle and quite probably both versions could be swapped without many problems. The most common in Spanish, the first one.

Comment: I would rather say "por" instead of "para". Tengo tarea por hacer, tengo algo por decir. In this case "por" acts like "left". I have tasks left, I have something left to say. But I think it changes the meaning. "Tengo algo que decir" means you have something important that cant be left without saying, while "Tengo algo por decir" means you have said things but you have not finished.

Comment: Como mucho podemos llamar a estas palabras partículas. *que* no sirve como preposición (de hecho, el DRAE lo reconoce incluso aquí como relativo para una cláusula) mientras *para* es definitivamente una preposición. No hay ninguna relación suficiente fuerte con el verbo *tener* como para llamarlos palabras *de régimen*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you could interchange them and the sentences would make sense, they don't quite mean the same in my opinion.

- Hay mucho para hacer: There's lots that can be done.
- Hay mucho por hacer: There's lots that's left to do.
- Hay mucho que hacer: There's lots that has to be done.

As far as I know, there is no special term for these words in contexts such as the above.

Answer (score -1):

Remember is different say work and homework.

I have work to do.

> Tengo mucho trabajo que hacer.
>   Tengo mucho trabajo por hacer
>   Tengo mucho trabajo para hacer.

I have homework to do.

> Tengo mucha tarea que hacer.
>   Tengo mucha tarea por hacer
>   Tengo mucha tarea para hacer.

You could use this options without problem.

I'm Spanish speaker

Comment: Ésto no contesta a la pregunta. Algo de más tal como la diferencia entre las palabras 'tarea' y 'trabajo' debería colgarse debajo de la publicación original.